# How to count number of columns in a table in Spark SQL (Databricks)?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm having trouble writing a statement to count the number of columns in Spark SQL. I tried using the information schema and using the table.columns, but both don't seem to work in Spark SQL. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Below is couple of lines you can add to count number of columns in Spark SQL,

**Pyspark Solution:**

```
df_cont = spark.creatDataframe() // use right funtion to create dataframe based on source 
print("Number of columns:"+str(len(df_cont.columns)))
```

**Scala Solution:**

```
val df_cont = spark.creatDataframe() // use right funtion to create dataframe based on source 
val length = df_cont.columns.length
println("Number of columns:"+length)
```